# Error while reading value from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying this code through which I'm getting the connection but I'm getting an error undefined variable.

> Connected to MySQL
>   SELECT * FROM headcont;
>   Notice: Undefined variable: myQuery in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myweb\index.php on line 86
>   No database selected

```
require("connection.php");

if($con)
{
    $qry="SELECT * FROM headcont;";
    //mysql_select_db('content');
    echo $qry;
    $result=mysql_query($qry) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            $title=$row[title];
            $desc=$row[description];
            echo $title;

        }
    }
```

I don't know what the issue is, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You're setting your query in `$qry`, but the variable you're passing to mysql_error is `$myQuery`, which isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I have corrected it to $qry but still I'm getting error like Notice: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myweb\index.php on line 88

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require("connection.php");

if($con)
{
    $qry="SELECT * FROM headcont;";
    mysql_select_db('content');
    echo $qry;
    $result=mysql_query($qry) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            $title=$row[title];
            $desc=$row[description];
            echo $title;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Still I'm getting error like Notice: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myweb\index.php on line 88

Comment: @Sau - you need to add quotes to that, and to the following line; it should be '$title = $row['title'];` and the same for description.

Comment: You are the man . you are absolutely correct great thanks a lot for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("connection.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `headcont` ") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $title = $row['title'];
 $desc = $row['description'];
 echo $title;
}
?>
```

Comment: Or he could just fix the issue that's causing notices. They're there for a reason, and suppressing them is not good practice.